# Getting NullPointerException while trying to deserialize json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting NullPointerException while trying to deserialize json. I am trying to deserialize only select JSON objects from https://api.covid19india.org/data.json

I have written code

```
import java.util.List;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class CovidData {
        List<Statewise> statewiseData;
        public List<Statewise> getStatewiseData() {
            return statewiseData;
        }
        public void setStatewiseData(List<Statewise> statewiseData) {
            this.statewiseData = statewiseData;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CovidData [statewiseData=" + statewiseData + "]";
        }
    }
```

Statewise.java

```
public class Statewise {
    @JsonProperty("active")
    String active;
    
    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Statewise [active=" + active + ", confirmed=" + confirmed + ", deaths=" + deaths + ", deltaconfirmed="
                + deltaconfirmed + ", deltadeaths=" + deltadeaths + ", deltarecovered=" + deltarecovered
                + ", lastupdatedtime=" + lastupdatedtime + ", migratedother=" + migratedother + ", recovered="
                + recovered + ", state=" + state + ", statecode=" + statecode + ", statenotes=" + statenotes + "]";
    }
    
}
```

calling method

```
@Test
    public void test1() {
        CovidData covidData=
        given()
        .when()
        .get("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json")
        .as(CovidData.class);
        
        List<Statewise> state=covidData.getStatewiseData();
        
        for (Statewise s : state)
            System.out.println(s.getActive());
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace of exception.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RestAssured.com.restassured.DeserializationTest2.test1(DeserializationTest2.java:18)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: I can see, there is no `statewiseData` in that JSON, and you are iterating over it in `for` loop. That might be the point of issue.

Comment: It is there, it is long JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned contains "statewise" property.
So to get it deserialized correctly you can either change the property `List<Statewise> statewiseData` to `List<Statewise> statewise` in your CovidData  class or add JsonProperty to map it to "statewise"

```
@JsonProperty("statewise")
List<Statewise> statewiseData;
```

Comment: I had forgotten to add json property to statewise. Thanks for pointing out